# JQuery Input Rails Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a search form on my page with two buttons - "news" and "events".

I can get the Rails search function to work correctly but I don't want a search form, I want the user to press one of the two buttons and the search to be executed.

I figure this probably has to be done with JQuery so when a button is clicked, either "news" or "events" are added to the rails input form and it submits the form.  Please appreciate where I'm going wrong here as the form won't submit and the search won't execute.

Application.js

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {

    $(".news-button").click(function(){
            $("#search").val("news");
            $("#news-search").submit();
        });

    $(".events-button").click(function(){
            $("#search").val("event");
            $("#news-search").submit();
        });

});
```

Index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag news_index_path, :method => 'get', :id => "news_search" do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
    <div class="col-sm-3 sort-buttons">
      <%= link_to "News", "", class: "btn btn-standard news-button" %>
      <%= link_to "Events", "", class: "btn btn-standard events-button" %>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <% @news.each do |n| %>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="news-wrap">
          <%= image_tag("#{n.image}", class: "img-responsive", alt: "Event/News Postings") %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

News.rb

```
class News < ApplicationRecord

    if Rails.env.development?
        def self.search(search)
          if search
            where('category LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
          else
            scoped
          end
        end
    end


end
```

News Controller:

```
  def index
    if params[:search]
        @news = News.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per_page(10) 
    else
        @news = News.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(10) 
    end
  end
```

Comment: Wrong id name spelled, change $("#news-search") to $("#news_search")

Comment: Thanks for this. I made that change and it still doesn't work.  It inserts the value but doesn't execute the search.  Any further thoughts?